# Please identify this nut covered cheese

Tags: cheese, food-identification

During breakfast at my hotel in Germany, I saw this kind of cheese. Can anyone help to name it?

As I can remember, it tastes a bit sweet on the nuts.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely the [“Castello” rum-and-nut covered cream cheese ring](https://www.arlafoods.de/produkte/castello/rum-125g-67693/) by Arla. The shape, the chopped nuts and slight sweetness are pretty unique.

Arla sells its products in supermarkets, but is also a big supplier for larger catering customers. You should be able to find it in most larger supermarkets.

Comment: It seems you are correct. I don't live either in Europe or US, so may not be able to find it :( Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Quite easy to make on your own, though. Get inventive!

Comment: @IconDaemon I am not sure what cheese i should use and never create cream cheese in first place lol

Comment: @Rendy If you search for "cheese log" you'll find plenty of different recipes. Look for one which specifically calls for cream cheese (note that the cream cheese package may be simply labeled "Philadelphia" outside the US), and which calls for sweet rather than savory ingredients.

Comment: The page on [cream cheese at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_cheese) uses Philadelphia-branded items in two of the three images! This brand is so ubiquitous in the US that wikipedia reports: _In Spain and Mexico, cream cheese is sometimes called by the generic name **queso filadelfia**_ ...